# position an absolute image from center?

Tags: html, css, positioning

is it possible to adjust the position of an image that is `absolute` away from the center and not from the left or the right?

Because if I use:

```
#marker {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    right:250px;
    top:400px;
}
```

It looks fine on my monitor but it looks off when viewed on a smaller laptop resolution.
What I need is to push the image away from the center so it will sit in the same place even on varied screen sizes.

Sorry if i'm not making much sense

Comment: can you share your code on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Absolute` positioning is calculated from the closest parent which having `relative` position. So What you can do is, add a parent which has relative position and put at the center(where you want your image).

Then you can add the absolute positioning to this image and it will calculated from the parents corner.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NKZnh/1)

Comment: How do I create a parent for my image? Sorry I'm not too clued up on some HTML and CSS

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out :) Works like a charm, thanks @Sachin

Comment: @Sachin - one small correction. You said "the recent parent having relative position". Actually, it's the closest parent that has relative, absolute, or fixed position.